# What's the best way to go about reading and updating data in a Table-per-Type database model in Razor/EF Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I followed the steps outlined in [this guide](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/table-per-type-inheritance-support-part-1-code-first/) to set up the database for my code-first razor application. This all worked fine, but I'm unsure how to actually use this database structure in my application. Using the code from t

```
public class PersonTpt
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerTpt
{
  [ForeignKey(nameof(Person))]
  public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK and FK pointing to PersonTpt
  public PersonTpt Person { get; set; }

  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeTpt
{
  [ForeignKey(nameof(Person))]
  public Guid Id { get; set; } // PK and FK pointing to PersonTpt
  public PersonTpt Person { get; set; }

  public decimal Turnover { get; set; }
}
```

In this case I've added the "Type" field to the PersonTpt class. In the actual application I have an "/Person/Edit" page with a form for editing the person, and the "Type" property is tied to a Select List. That dropdown will have values that correspond to either CustomerTpt or EmployeeTpt, and I want the form to add the appropriate fields depending on the selection made. In my database model the "Person" class can only ever have one sub-class, and there will be a large number of sub-classes (possibly hundreds) though I'm only showing two to keep the example short

So a couple questions I have about all of this...

1. How would I go about actually using this data-model on the Edit page? Would I just need to create a partial view for every possible sub-class? Or is there a way to pass a "variable" sub-class to the page model?
2. Is there a way in EF Core to query the database for a "Person" while retrieving the sub-class automatically (e.g. doing a large join), or would I just need to hard-code logic to get the sub-class based on what the Type is? In the example from the guide I linked they only went backwards, which is more obvious since that's where the link lives
3. One thought I had was to just store the class data in a dictionary object (property name/value) but then I don't think I can use the razor TagHelpers in the form, right (e.g. asp-for, asp-validation-for, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How would I go about actually using this data-model on the Edit page? Would I just need to create a partial view for every possible sub-class? Or is there a way to pass a "variable" sub-class to the page model?

You could, but you could also just check the type of the class and output some additional HTML controls if necessary:

```cs
if (person is CustomerTpt customer)
{
    // Do something with customer here.
}
```

> 2. Is there a way in EF Core to query the database for a "Person" while retrieving the sub-class automatically (e.g. doing a large join), or would I just need to hard-code logic to get the sub-class based on what the Type is? In the example from the guide I linked they only went backwards, which is more obvious since that's where the link lives

You could add navigation properties to the `PersonTpt` class as well:

```cs
public class PersonTpt
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }

  public CustomerTpt Customer { get; set; }
  public EmployeeTpt Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could query them as follows:

```cs
var personsWithRelations = context.Persons
    .Include(p => p.Customer)
    .Include(p => p.Employee)
    .ToList();
```

> 3. One thought I had was to just store the class data in a dictionary object (property name/value) but then I don't think I can use the razor TagHelpers in the form, right (e.g. asp-for, asp-validation-for, etc.)?

I am not sure what your approach here is. You might want to provide some code (working or not) to get your idea across.

Comment: For your first point, how would that actually work? I'm not clear on how the code is going to know if the Person class "is" the CustomerTpt class. I can give that a try if it's that simple though

For the second point, this seems like a decent possibility. But say in the case where I have 100 different sub-classes, I'm going to need a giant if statement to see which one it actually has, right?

Comment: I'm not sure the best way to put code in a comment, so I responded to your other question in a separate answer

Comment: Since the "sub classes" are not really sub classes, because they don't inherit from `Person`, the `person` variable in my example either needs to be of type `object`, or all your sub classes must implement the same interface and the `person` variable would then be of that interface type. You can then test the variable using the `is` operator for the actual type (or use the new [Switch Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions)). You could also use the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern#C#) instead.

Comment: A giant if statement or a switch expression would be one way to implement this. You could also use reflection or implement an interface with a method, that contains the sub class specific algorithm that you want to execute. In the latter case, you would not need to know, what sub class you are dealing with. (This issue would also arise, when the classes were actually derived from `Person`, and not just for your TPT emulating case here.)

Comment: Don't give an answer to your question with another question. Either answer your own question for good, if other answers are not satisfactory, or add to your your initial question by editing it.

Comment: BTW, EF Core 5 has true TPT support (see [Relational: TPT inheritance mapping pattern](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/2266) and [Table-per-type (TPT) inheritance mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#table-per-type-tpt-inheritance-mapping)).